# Javascript HTML Progress Bar to monitor the running of whole Perl CGI script:

Tags: javascript, html, perl, progress-bar, real-time

I have been unable to find a solution I can understand.
Basically I have a form in the HTML, which submits to a Perl CGI script, this script runs a number of processes which can take approximately 5 minutes, before it returns a results page.
I have attempted everything I have found on the internet from CGI::ProgressBar to Ajax, to attempting a simple timed progress bar from HTML5.
I will take any solution from basing length of time (15,000kb per minute fro script running time), how can I implement the progress bar to run for this input file size in the form submission on a timer?
Alternatively, how can I set up the progress bar to begin upon clicking the submit button, and then run to a set maximum time, whilst printing statements as though in real time?
I have no experience in javascript, so please be kind, learning here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=791376

Comment: @mpapec Seen that, I've literally seen everything google comes up with, it doesn't work. It prints only at the end of the script despite the autoflush buffering stuff. This is last resort, I've been searching for days.

Comment: Server might also do some buffering, so send some chars in addition to force output `print " " x 4096;`

Comment: @mpapec I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Is this something that will cause the perl script to print statements in real time whilst the script is still running onto the webpage? Where should that be written? The server is very basic, running on linux.

Comment: It should go after every `<script>..</script>` part. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=791397

Comment: @mpapec It didn't work, same issue as before, script doesn't print until it has finished.